# AngularJS model introspection/reflection

Tags: angularjs, reflection, batarang

Is it possilbe to introspect/reflect of the model in Angular app, where you can change the scope and traverse it? Something like batarang have but that will allow to change the values.

If not is it possilbe to monkey patch Angular code (by including another script on the page) that will make it possilbe?

Comment: There is project https://github.com/rev087/ng-inspector that show the scope of the app and it have a plan to expand/collapse and edit the scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Accessing/Modyfing scope properties**

Angular's `$scope` objects are plain old JS objects, so thay can be manipulated the standard way.
E.g. `someScope.someProp` retrieves the value of a property, while `someScope.someProp = someValue` sets the value of a property.

---

**2. Letting Angular know**

Modifying the object's properties is one thing - making Angular aware of the change is another.
Angular will not know about our modifications, until it runs a `$digest` cycle. If we want to apply the changes right away, we can explicitely trigger a `$digest` cycle, by using `someScope.$apply()`.

---

**3. Getting hold of a scope**

In order to get a reference to the scope associated with a DOM element, we need to have a reference to the corresponding DOM Node object, wrap it in `angular.element` and execute its `scope()` method.
Something like this:

```
<body class="ng-scope">

var someScope = angular.element(document.body).scope();
```

Furthermore, if we want to access the `$rootScope` (the parent scope of all scopes), we can use the injector to inject the `$rootScope` service:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

var injector = angular.element(document.documentElement).injector();
var rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
```

---

**4. Traversing the scope-tree**

Once we get hold of a scope object, we might want to traverse the scope-tree. Every scope has the following properties (among others):

- `$parent`: The parent scope of this scope (if any).
- `$$nextSibling`: The next sibling scope of this scope (if any).
  (Sibling scopes are scopes that have the same `$parent`)
- `$$childHead`: The first child scope of this scope (if any).

In order to traverse the branch of the scope-tree with `someScope` as its root:

```
var scopes = [someScope];
while (scopes.length) {
    var scope = scopes.shift();
    console.log(scope);
    if (scope.$$nextSibling) { scopes.unshift(scope.$$nextSibling); }
    if (scope.$$childHead) { scopes.unshift(scope.$$childHead); }
}
```

---

E.g. to traverse the whole scope-tree, you can use the following snippet:

```
var injector = angular.element(document.body).injector();
var rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');

var scopes = [rootScope];
while (scopes.length) {
    var scope = scopes.shift();
    report(scope);
    if (scope.$$nextSibling) { scopes.unshift(scope.$$nextSibling); }
    if (scope.$$childHead) { scopes.unshift(scope.$$childHead); }
}

function report(scope) {
    var str = '' + scope.$id;

    while (scope.$parent) {
        str = scope.$parent.$id + ' => ' + str;
        scope = scope.$parent;
    }

    console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I can create model introspection manipulation tool for Angular.

Comment: @jcubic: You probably know that already, but Batarang is open-source, so it is a good place to start anyway.

Comment: It didn't allow to change the scope so I thought that it was not what I want, also it require to refresh the browser in order to see the scope so I thought that it modify Angular app or Angular itself in order to see the model. Maybe I just fork Batarang and add feature that will allow to modify scope.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I know it doesn't do exactly what you want, but it seems to have part of the problem solved, so parts of it should be useful as a starting point (in order not to re-invent the wheel).

Comment: I've written a tiny Firebug plugin called [AngScope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/) that helps you inspect `$scope` objects. It displays them in Firebug's DOM inspector. From there you can select the object to use it in the console, edit properties and call `$apply()`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the way, here is a code that change the scope outside of Angular:

```
var $scope = angular.element($('.section:eq(0)')).scope();
$scope.$apply(function() {
   scope.color = "blue";
});
```

the `angular.element().scope()` will return scope and can be investigated. Not sure about how to traverse scope tree, but this is good starting point. If there is no scope traverse you could just traverse the DOM and check if there is new scope on that DOM element.

Comment: instead of angular element as Michał Dudak wrote in his answer you can just use jQuery `$('.section:eq(0)').scope();`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the scope by calling the `scope()` method on an object returned by `angular.element()` (or `$()`, if you also use jQuery), e.g. `angular.element(".foo").scope()`. There's no direct way of accessing child scopes. But knowing that all elements that have a new scope associated with them have the `ng-scope` class, you can traverse the element tree instead.

```
$(".foo").find(".ng-scope").each(function() {
  var scope = $(this).scope();
});
```

This, however can be a bit tricky, as `find()` will find all nodes below `.foo`, regardless of their depth. You could use `children()` instead but it may not yield any results as direct descendants of `.foo` may not create a new scope.

Comment: Good to know that you can use jquery to get element instead of angular.element and use scope as the plugin. But you can traverse the scope - read @ExpertSystem answer.

Comment: @jcubic: Regarding your comment on jQuery: `.scope()` is an Angular-specific method. If you include both jQuery and Angular (jQuery script must come before AngularJS) then `angular.element()` is an alias of `$()` so anything you can do with the former can also be done with the latter. In case jQuery is not present (or it is loaded after AngularJS), then `angular.element()` "falls back" to using the integrated "leight" version of jQuery (jqLite).